# Navigation in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

How to navigate from one ViewController to Another in iOS.As i was previously working on Android It was intent. I am not able to see proper documentation for iOS using swift. So please help me how to navigate from one view controller to another on a button click ! (I know button click func)

Comment: Have you at least try to google about this.

Comment: "I am not able to see proper documentation for iOS using swift"

Answer (score 0):

In your Main Storyboard press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + button and drag it to the another viewController. By this clicking on button will take you to another view controller.